# Script blocked due to MIME type mismatch on Heroku

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

This type of errors I have seen first time not able to get, Whats the actual problem with the same.

The resource from bootstrap-multiselect.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

The application works on local machine perfect, but when deploy to the heroku server then this problem comes for the application and the plugin also not working.

Can someone please help me the same ???

Answer (score -1):

The script and styleSheet elements will reject responses with incorrect MIME types if the server sends the response header "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff". This is a security feature that helps prevent attacks based on MIME-type confusion.

This change impacts the browser's behavior when the server sends the "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header on its responses.

If the "nosniff" directive is received on a response received by a styleSheet reference, It will not load the "stylesheet" file unless the MIME type matches **"text/css"**.

If the "nosniff" directive is received on a response retrieved by a script reference, It will not load the "script" file unless the MIME type matches one of the following values:

- "application/ecmascript"
- "application/javascript"
- "application/x-javascript"
- "text/ecmascript"
- "text/javascript"
- "text/jscript"
- "text/x-javascript"
- "text/vbs"
- "text/vbscript"

Comment: The reason is very obvious, but a solution is not.